# In order to publish the apps with PackageManager API access from June onwards , should I want to remove the <queries>in the manifest?

Tags: android, google-play, android-package-managers, android-13

In order to **Publish** the Android App to the **Playstore**, we should have to remove the queries in the manifest `<permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />`.
I read the documents in this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-query-all-packages-permission) from **GooglePlay**, but my question is should I want to remove the `<queries>` tag as well? because

> **I didn't see anywhere they mentioned removing the tag below, they only said to remove the permission**

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent>
 </queries>
```